# What's the optimal method to archive a lot of mailings?

Tags: mailing

I look after a Civi install which has hundreds of completed mailings. I'd like to tidy things up a bit by archiving a lot of the older mailings, but there's no way that I can see to achieve this using the user interface.

Would it be OK simply to set the is_archived field in the civicrm_mailing table to '1'? I know for a lot of stuff tinkering directly with the database isn't a good idea, but in this case?

Ideally the mailing search results pages would work in the same way as contact search results pages and have checkboxes and an action menu, but that's not evident in the version currently running here (4.7.29 I think).

Comment: mailing.is_archived looks safe to set through the database. To be a little safer I'd try it on one mailing first

Comment: @Graham, modifying the table work for you? We have the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We have done some recent work on an Extension through which you can nominate a 'before' date and it then cleans out the Mailings along with the abundance of Activities, Activity Contacts etc.

So this is not 'Archiving' as per the OP, this is deletion and does not answer your question but am hoping it proves a useful answer for others who might stumble on this. We will be writing up a blog shortly. On the big databases we are testing this on it is clearing out millions of rows of data and speeding up other queries particularly related to Actvities.

Extension is at https://github.com/jitendrapurohit/nz.co.fuzion.deleteoldbulkmailings

NOTE: Usual warnings apply. Turn off logging before running this.

Comment: Hi @petednz, I'd be very interested in this.  Do you have more details?